# React Draft Wysiwyg - Using custom toolbar icons instead of standard inline toolbar images

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Is there a way to replace the inline toolbar images with custom icons like ones from `React Icons`?

Code (Toolbar Options):

```js
import { AiOutlineUnorderedList } from 'react-icons/ai'

export const toolbarOptions = {
  options: ['list', 'link'],
  list: {
    options: ['unordered', 'ordered'],
    unordered: {
      icon: <AiOutlineUnorderedList />, //does not work
      className: undefined,
    },
  },
  link: {
    options: ['link'],
  },
}
```

I have also tried to use `<img src="./path-to-svg"/>` however that does not work as well...

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to provide the src or file path

```
unordered: { 
 icon: "../path-to.svg",
 className: undefined
}
```